# Getting output only from 1st page TIFF to hocr extract

Tags: windows, python, ocr, tesseract-ocr

[[Sample Image]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O8OenU22YyeorFElya7fzxa5-WmbjuED/view?usp=sharing)

I seek your guidance in the code given below. Iam running this code to extract text from multipage TIFF to hocr format. Iam getting an output from the 1st page of TIFF but rest of the pages are omitted.

```python
# Python program to extract text from all the images in a folder
# storing the text in corresponding files in a different folder
# This is for hocr output, but there is error of getting only 1 page
    
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as pt
import os
pt.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
     
def main():
    # path for the folder for getting the raw images
    path ="D:\\input"
    # path for the folder for getting the output
    tempPath ="D:\\output"
 
    # iterating the images inside the folder
    for imageName in os.listdir(path):
             
        inputPath = os.path.join(path, imageName)
        img = Image.open(inputPath)
 
        # applying ocr using pytesseract for python
           
        text = pt.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(img, extension = 'hocr', config = (r'--oem 3 --psm 6'), lang ="eng")
         
        fullTempPath = os.path.join(tempPath, 'time_'+imageName+".hocr")
        print(text)
  
        # saving the text for every image in a separate .hocr file
        file1 = open(fullTempPath, "wb")
        file1.write(text)
        file1.close()
  
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: [Python PIL For Loop to work with Multi-image TIFF - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602525/python-pil-for-loop-to-work-with-multi-image-tiff)

Comment: Hi , thanks. I tried to substitute the code you have suggested but could not get a result. May be i was doing it wrong way.

Comment: you could add (in question) link to some multipage TIFF for tests.

Comment: @furas i have attached as an image, not finding an option to upload tiff, Also could not find a suitable tiff sample link in google search.

Comment: the only idea: put example TIFF on Google Drive or similar portal and put link to this file.

Comment: @furas, Thank you! for the suggestion. great ! I have added with the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I checked it can get `filename` instead of `PILLOW.Image`

```
text = pt.image_to_pdf_or_hocr('D:\\input\\Best time to visit.tiff', extension='hocr', config=(r'--oem 3 --psm 6'), lang="eng")
```

So it can runs `tesseract` with original `tiff` and it converts all pages to one text `hocr`.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I took your `tiff` and code from link in my comment and I created code which saves every page in separated file. It uses `img.seek(page)` to select page. And it works for me  with your file.

```python
from PIL import Image
import os

folder = '/home/furas/Desktop'
filename = 'Best time to visit.tiff'

img = Image.open(os.path.join(folder, filename))

page = 0

while True:
    try:
        img.seek(page)

        filename = f'page-{page+1}.png'
        print('saving...', filename)

        img.save(os.path.join(folder, filename))

        page += 1
    except EOFError:
        # Not enough frames in img
        break
```

Something similar works for me in your code

```python
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as pt
import os

pt.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
     
# path for the folder for getting the raw images
path = "D:\\input"

# path for the folder for getting the output
tempPath = "D:\\output"

# iterating the images inside the folder
for imageName in os.listdir(path):
 
    # only images   
    if imageName.lower().endswith(('.tiff', '.jpg', '.png')):
        print(imageName)
        
        inputPath = os.path.join(path, imageName)
        img = Image.open(inputPath)
    
        page = 0
        while True:
            try:
        
                img.seek(page)
                text = pt.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(img, extension='hocr', config=(r'--oem 3 --psm 6'), lang="eng")
        
                print('page...', page)
                page += 1
         
                fullTempPath = os.path.join(tempPath, f"time_{imageName}_{page}.hocr")
                #print(text)
        
                # saving the text for every image in a separate .hocr file
                file1 = open(fullTempPath, "wb")
                file1.write(text)
                file1.close()
            except EOFError:
                # Not enough frames in img
                break
```

It has to write every page in separated `.hocr` because if you try to write many `.hocr` in one file then it creates broken `.hocr`

To write all pages in one file you would need to use plain text.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @furas your solution perfectly worked for me, probably i was trying to force the multipage output as single hocr file. I was trying to concat the output file to get my desired final output concat = ''.join([open(f).read() for f in files]) any method i can implement in the master code itself

Comment: you can't join `hocr` because they use XML and every XML has header and keep data in <body> </body>` - and when you join then you get many headers in the middle of `XML`  (and many `<body>`) but it may have only one header and one `<body>`. You would have to write code which get data from all `<body>`and put in one `<body>`. You may try to use `lxml`, `beautifulsoup`, or other module for `XML`. But it may other problem. every element has assigned text with `x y width height` and if put all together then you will have many elements with similar `x y` but it needs to be moved.

Comment: @furas, Thank you for elucidating on this. I think it is more complicated to run on python. I have to learn on beautifulsoup format. Pls suggest if any tutorial for this. I have rather decided to use CMD prompt to run HOCR which has perfect output. So technically i have to prepare images separately and run CMD separately.

Comment: I would rather eager to understand is there any method to use cmd prompt code (tesseract inputimage.tiff output image.hocr ) in notepad and retrieve in python. If it works than i can combine pre processing of image in python and use notepad to activate cmd prompt to output .hocr.

Comment: if `tesseract` can create one `.hocr` with all pages from `tiff` then use module `subprocess` to run directly `tesseract`. `subprocess.run(["tesseract", "inputimage.tiff", "output image.hocr"])`

Comment: OR you could check if `pytesseract` can get `filename` instead `PIL.image` because probably it also use `subprocess` to run `tesseract`

Comment: I checked and `pt.image_to_pdf_or_hocr()` can get path to original `tiff` and it will convert all pages to one text `hocr`